# Memory free function printing random numbers with binary tree implementation

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

I am writing a program that uses the binary tree data structure. When writing the routine to free all the nodes I came across a peculiar problem that I can't explain.

This is the routine:

```
void destroy_tree(NodeT **tree){

    if( *tree != NULL ){
        destroy_tree( &(*tree)->left );
            free( (*tree)->left );
        destroy_tree( &(*tree)->right );
            free( (*tree)->right );
    }
    return;
}
```

Basically a 2-star pointer is passed to the function. It checks whether each node is NULL before proceeding to free the pointers. `NodeT` is a structure containing a left and right pointers to NodeT structures; these are the pointers I am trying to free.

The structure is defined as:

```
typedef struct{
    int val;
    struct tnode *right, *left;
}NodeT;
```

Without the free() calls nothing happens as you would expect. However, when the free calls are uncommented the output looks like this:

[image]

Each time I run the program the number blocks will change but they are always repeating with an eventual crash.

The original call to this function is what you might expect,

```
destroy_tree(&rootNode);
```

Where rootNode is: `NodeT *rootNode`;

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need this to be written with double pointers? This would be simpler with single pointers.

Comment: Where is that output coming from? Who is printing that?

Comment: I agree - but this is a project and we were asked to implement 2-star pointers. It would be much simpler.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves The output only happens when I call free(). If I uncomment free() nothing happens.

Comment: I do not see any code writing output, so where is your output coming from? Why don't you set left and right to NULL after free-ing them?

Comment: @sherrellbc being asked to do something does not mean you __have__ to do it if it is useless. There, your function has absolutely NO use of the second level of pointing, so either you take it out, or you find some use to it (setting the previous memory of the tree to NULLs for example)

Comment: @WernerHenze Exactly. I do not have anything printing these statements in my program yet this is the output when the free() calls are enabled. If I uncomment them there is no output. I have not gotten that far yet. It may be a good idea for debugging purposes, but the nodes are freed anyway.

Comment: If you are sure that free() prints these numbers, then I'ld run the program in the debugger and trace into free to see why free prints out numbers and what they mean. I'ld be surprised if free() really prints out just numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to free current node instead:

```
void destroy_tree(NodeT **tree){

    if( *tree != NULL ){
        destroy_tree( &(*tree)->left );
        destroy_tree( &(*tree)->right );
        free(*tree);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: This worked great. I was making this much more difficult. I was freeing both child nodes and then, upon returning to the caller, freeing the parent's child node which would be the previous current node. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what kind of system you're running on, but I would guess that the printing is coming from a heap diagnostic routine complaining about heap corruption.

So the problem is probably that your tree isn't actually a tree -- a `NodeT` appears twice in the tree (so it's a DAG), or worse, one of the pointers points at a parent (there's a loop in the tree.)  Either of those will lead to heap corruption (undefined behavior), which can cause anything to happen.

I would suggest running with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or some other heap debugging tool to narrow things down a bit, but that still won't tell you where the real problem is (which is somewhere in the code that creates the tree.)

Comment: Each node in the tree is a NodeT struct. I have been quite careful to keep the tree as a tree, but there is always the possibility. Thank you for the suggested software.